# how to change font awesome icons on click?

Tags: html

I'm use Font awesome icons in my vBulletin style and i want to change the (minus) icon to (plus) when click ! Is there a way to do it ?

```
    <a rel="nofollow" style="float:left" href="#" onclick="return
 toggle_collapse('forumbit_$forumid')">
 <span style="color:#24356C;" >
<i class="fa fa-minus-square-o fa-2x"></i>
</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this question(and the answer) can help you do what you want :)

[Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Comment: i have tried to do and i've succeeded, but when i clicked for one time the icon is changed from minus to plus icon , then remain plus until Reload the page again to return - but it works without problems here http://jsfiddle.net/WRONG_WAY/ub5jumo0/

Comment: I am not sure why that would not work but I devised a little check in JSfiddle you may try:
http://jsfiddle.net/ub5jumo0/5/

Answer (score -1):

Assign an id to your icon, e.g.

```
<i class="fa fa-minus-square-o fa-2x" id="i-1"></i>
```

The id can be dynamic value like 'i-$forumid' depend on how you generate your html.

In your toggle_collapse('forumbit_$forumid') function,
Add

```
var e = document.getElementById('i-1');
if (e.classList.contains('fa-plus-square-o')) {
  e.classList.toggle('fa-plus-square-o');
} else {
  e.classList.add('fa-plus-square-o');
}
```

or

```
function toggle_collapse(forumID) {
  ...

  var iconID = 'i-' + formumID.replace('forumbit_','')
  var e = document.getElementById(iconID);
  if (e.classList.contains('fa-plus-square-o')) {
    e.classList.toggle('fa-plus-square-o');
  } else {
    e.classList.add('fa-plus-square-o');
  }

  ...
}
```